# how to enable database auto-reconnect in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

and the database is MYSQL

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  What are you using to connect to the database, the mysql extension, mysqli, or an abstraction layer?  What kind of error message are you getting, etc.?

Comment: @ruquay, Actually the question is pretty specific. It doesn't matter if you are using mysqli or the older mysqli. Shows that you don't understand what [auto-reconnect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html) means. This question is as specific as   http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1003841/1

Comment: @Pacerier thanks for the link to the manual. I am quite amazed at your vast knowledge. Also the tone of your comment shows that you understand what basic human decency is. I am really in awe.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes when your MySQL connection opened for too long, the connection to the DB will be dropped when the time without a query exceeds the wait_timeout value in my.cnf. You will get "MySQL server has gone away" timeout error.

This is how I implement auto reconnect in my code:

```
class databaseClass {
    var $conn;
    var $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $this->db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->conn);
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        mysql_close($this->conn);
    }

    public function reconnect() {
        $this->disconnect();
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function queryCompanyExist($company) {
        //auto reconnect if MySQL server has gone away
        if (!mysql_ping($this->conn)) $this->reconnect();

        $query =  "SELECT name FROM company WHERE name='$company'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) print mysql_error() . "\r\n";
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
}
```

Refer here for more infomation about [mysql_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php)

Comment: great answer! most of the net tells us to increase limits, but for some edge cases this is not advisable as we do not know how long something may take. This is ideal for those situations.

Answer (score 6):

From the C mysql API:

my_bool reconnect = 0;
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/auto-reconnect.html

From PHP mysqli in php.ini set the global: 
mysqli.reconnect = On
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.reconnect

For the PHP PDO mysql driver it should be available through PDO::setAttribute but I am unable to find documentation indicating that it is implemented. The code appears to be attempting to respect the MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT which is now required by mysql but to have failed to do so in the initial implementation (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58863). The intent of the patch in 58863 is to allow:
   new PDO('mysql:host=xxx', 'xx', 'xx',array(PDO::MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=>true));

The reasons why the reconnect occurs are various but commonly because a pooled set of connections contains a mature connection which has timed out due to a lack of use. By default mysql connections time out after 8 hours. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html

For side effects of a reconnection see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/auto-reconnect.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [mysql_ping()](http://php.net/mysql_ping) function to test the status of the connection and reconnect when it returns `false`. mysql_ping() will even reconnect for you if you're using a MySQL before 5.0.13 as mentioned on that documentation page; "Since MySQL 5.0.13, automatic reconnection feature is disabled.".

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which will ping the database via connection and in case it down, reconnect it again and then proceed the query or whatever you want, also take a look on [mysqli](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) php library, it can be useful for you.

PS. Also could be useful to implement [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in order to maintain the database connection, once created it will connect to database and then you can implement the method called getConnection which each time will proceed with the check I've described above.

PPS. You can use an exception, try you query, whenever it fails catch an exception, reconnect and try again.

Comment: Will be pretty slow this way,seems?

Comment: What will be slow? To check connection each time? You have to do some trade off, what is more important connectivity assurance or data safety. I would like just to point what any way, to be able to ensure you still have any connection you need to make a check each time, before you start the update. Even if you will succeed to configure mysql server to reconnect automatically on connection lost, it will take time to discover it and maybe you will proceed with query exactly at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the query fails anyway. By checking the error code you can tell if it failed because of no connection and reconnect. Just make sure you keep track of reconnection attempts so you don't get stuck in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to "reconnect" in the first place? How/Why are you getting disconnected? In PHP you connect at the beginning of the script and the connection is closed automatically at the end of the script.

There's no need to call `mysql_close` in your script at all (and it would be silly to "automatically reconnect" if you explicitly closed the connection).

You can try [mysql_pconnect](http://www.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect) is that's what you're looking for. The connection will then stay open permanently, and other scripts that connect can use the connection.

Comment: Many reasons for auto-reconnect, just by the first paragraph of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/auto-reconnect.html .....