# PHP activerecord mysql server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, phpactiverecord, wrench

I'm using [php-activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) for a short while now and i absolutely love it. Php-activerecord is an open source ORM library based on the [ActiveRecord pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). However, i recently tried to use it in combination with a websocket application based on [Wrench](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench).

This works perfectly but to start the script the application has to run as a daemon on linux in order to make the websockets always availeble. After a short while of not using the application and then trying to use it again it throws some database exceptions:

At first it gives a warning:

```
PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=XXXXX in /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php on line 322
```

Then it throws a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php:322
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php(322): PDOStatement->execute(Array)

#1 /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(218): ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SELECT * FROM ...', Array)

#2 /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(209): ActiveRecord\Table->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM `...', Array, false, NULL)

#3 /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php(1567): ActiveRecord\Table->find(Array)

#4 in /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php on line 325
```

It seems like php-activerecord is keeping the mysql connection open all the time that the websocket server is running, this ofcourse should not be a problem if it then automatically tried to reconnect and run the query again. But it doens't.

I've read something about setting `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT`. But i'm not sure if that works or how to set that option using php-activerecord. Does anybody here have some experience in this area?

Edit: Here are my global timeout config variables

```
VARIABLE_NAME                   VARIABLE_VALUE  
DELAYED_INSERT_TIMEOUT          300
WAIT_TIMEOUT                    28800
CONNECT_TIMEOUT                 10
LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT               31536000
INNODB_ROLLBACK_ON_TIMEOUT      OFF
THREAD_POOL_IDLE_TIMEOUT        60
NET_WRITE_TIMEOUT               60
INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT        50
INTERACTIVE_TIMEOUT             28800
DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT_LONG           50000000
SLAVE_NET_TIMEOUT               3600
DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT_SHORT          10000
NET_READ_TIMEOUT                30
```

Comment: Do you have full control of the database config? Can you list all the timeouts that you have set in your config? If your config is empty, select your global variables from mysql and post all rows that contain 'timeout'.

Comment: @Dimitri yes i have full control, and i've just edited my question.

Comment: Have you checked [how to enable database auto-reconnect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982442/how-to-enable-database-auto-reconnect-in-php). According to it, it is not possible to set `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT` in PDO (and php-activerecord uses PDO). Perhaps a workaround is to execute simple query each hour?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the connection going more than 8 hours?

Comment: IMO, `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT` is not a good solution. Read my answer below. It is based on actual implementation.

Comment: @RTB Using Active Record, then you got what you deserve. Active Record as a pattern is an abomination to any DB developer and so is any library based on that pattern. Just learn to use RDBMS like they are designed to be used, or use a non-relational data store if all you want is a passive data store for your classes.

Comment: Have you implemented socket service in PHP? Can you provide me a bit of code responsible for holding connection with DB? Have you tried connect DB via `.sock` instead tcp?

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks for asking ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP ActiveRecord uses PDO.  There is absolutely no way to close a PDO connection, it is the wrong DB layer for long running background tasks.

You can try to *influence* the disconnection of a PDO connection with the following snippet.

```
//if not using ZF2 libraries, disconnect in some other way
$db->getDriver()->getConnection()->disconnect()
$db = NULL;
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Disconnect, set your reference to null, then run the garbage collector.  The hope is that that will call the PDO's internal __destruct method to actually close the connection.

**You** must manage your DB connections in your own long running script.  You must disconnect if your worker hasn't had to process work in a while, and you must reconnect when you have work.

The real solution is to not use PDO and disconnect and reconnect normally.

If you simply set both server and client library timeouts to be infinite, you'll run into problems with out of control scripts that never die, forcing you to restart the entire server (not a good idea to mess with timeouts).

EDIT:  I actually had this exact problem and used this exact solution at work last year.  This solved 99% of my problems.  But still, every once in a while there wass a stray connection exception that I could not catch and try to reconnect.  I simply restart the processes once a day to rid myself of those stray connection errors.  That's why my answer is, don't use PDO.  Switch now and get real control over disconnects and reconnects.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Try doing the following change.

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

If you have a lot of request set this and don't set it to bigger because its related with your environment.

```
max_connections=1000
```

Adding this line into `my.cnf` file might solves your problem. Restart the MySQL service once you are done with the change.

Read more on [MySQL server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

If it does not work try [this](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/1/topics/54-reconnecting-to-lost-server-connection) auto-reconnect function as well.

Comment: Automatically reconnecting can cause trouble because of state information that is lost.  In particular, if you are in a transaction, that will be rolled back by the disconnect.  Continuing after the reconnection could lead to lost/modified data.

Answer (score 1):

As said, MySQL in PHP scripts times out when there is no communication between the two for some time.
That is a good thing, since idle connections would eat up your server resources.

"Server has gone away" error mostly happens when a relatively lenghty computation happens between two queries.

In order to prevent that, you can

- Periodically execute a `SELECT 1` query during your execution
- Create a wrapper around your queries which checks if connection is valid before executing
- Use answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982442/how-to-enable-database-auto-reconnect-in-php)

However, I believe that reconfiguring MySQL to keep connection open for longer encourages careless programming and would advice against it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be also the size of the query, as sometimes ORMs combine the queries to improve performance.

Try setting max_allowed_packet=128M, at least should be useful as a diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is not handling multiple, concurrent connections and queries You could set "infinite" timeouts. This won't affect DB resources significantly. Best approach is to send ping packets (SELECT 1) to renew timeout and make connection kept-alive.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve such problem, I suggest you to:

1. Distribute your processes using Gearman job server (http://gearman.org/)
2. Manage those processes easily using Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/)

Here is how.

Run your web socket application as a daemon, just like you already did now (perhaps using cron). Or even better, manage it using Supervisor. Configure it so that Supervisor start it when Supervisor starts and autorestart the daemon if it dies.

Example configuration:

```
[program:my-daemon]
command=/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/daemon/script
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Next, instead of running the query processing inside the application daemon, create a Gearman Worker to handle it. Once registered, the Worker will be waiting to be run/called. You must call the Worker from your websocket application, together with the necessary workload parameter if necessary (refer to Gearman website for this workload term explanation).

In Worker, set it to stop/exit when it already finish the job requested by the daemon. With this, you won't have the "mysql server has gone away problem" because the connection is immediately closed.

Finally, we have to make the Worker available all time just like the daemon. So, similar to the daemon, configure Supervisor to autostart and autorestart it when the Worker dies/stops, like that:

```
[program:my-worker]
command=/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/worker/script
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Another interesting thing is that you can add as many Workers as you like to be alive waiting. Just add the following configuration:

```
numprocs=9 #change it to any number
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d #to identity worker number
```

Since we told Supervisor to autorestart each processes, we always have constant Workers running in background.

Here is another explanation about this strategy: http://www.masnun.com/2011/11/02/gearman-php-and-supervisor-processing-background-jobs-with-sanity.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: @ArunPoudel why is that? I implemented those in production environment. The mysql server has gone away is because the connection is open too long, and PHP is not suitable for long run.

Comment: Downvoter, please read the strategy carefully. Read the link I post too! The "mysql server has gone away" problem seems like simple to solve, but it is not.

Comment: Yes, I did and it is in no way related to the post. The issue the OP's having is pretty different from what you are trying to solve.

Comment: @ArunPoudel Why is it not related? It solves the problem "mysql server has gone away".

Comment: Yes, using an insane approach. It's not about just solving the problem. But doing it in an idiomatic way. There are other ways of handling such kind of issues and reconnection flag is one of them.

Comment: @ArunPoudel So now you're saying it is related, but idiomatic? If you have other solution, write your own answer. That's the preferred way of SO. *actually I don't understand what you mean with idiomatic.